# I cannot update Xcode and use Command Line Developer Tools

Tags: command-line, xcode, mac-appstore

I have had this issue since yesterday.

For example: I am trying to use git command but MacOS throwing a prompt to ask my installation permission and I am clicking to install button and after the installation I try to use git command then that prompt appears again.

Also, I cannot update xcode on App Store. The progress circle has been animating for a long time. It has 125.1 GB free space.

[image]

My xcode-select version is

> *2395*

and output of `xcode-select --install` is

> *xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates*

Comment: Is Xcode currently installed? If so, delete it and reinstall

Comment: @Ezekiel I did it and it's installed now but I still have an issue with command line tools.

Comment: In Xcode settings, go to Locations and make sure that the right thing is selected for the Command Line Tools entry

Comment: Thanks @Ezekiel. I updated xcode and after update I launched it and it installed some component itself and then solved my problem.